# Swift 3 - Invalid conversion from throwing function type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and 
I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error even doing the `do catch` treatment.
I've being reading similar questions and so far none of them solved this error :
 `Invalid conversion from throwing function type '(_) throws -> (). to non-throwing function type '([BeaconModel]) -> ()'` at the line  `BeaconModel.fetchBeaconsFromRestApi(completionHandler: { .....`

The piece of code with the error:

```
do{

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let db = try Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")

    let beaconsTbl = Table("beacons")
    let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
    let uuid = Expression<String>("uuid")
    let major = Expression<String>("major")
    let minor = Expression<String>("minor")

    try db.run(beaconsTbl.create { t in
        t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
        t.column(uuid)
        t.column(major)
        t.column(minor)
    })

    BeaconModel.fetchBeaconsFromRestApi(completionHandler: {
        beacons in
        for item in beacons{

            let insert = beaconsTbl.insert(id <- item.id!, uuid <- item.uuid!, major <- item.major!, minor <- item.minor!)
            try db.run(insert)
        }
    })

} catch {
    print("Error creating the database")
}
```

The fetch method:

```
static func fetchBeaconsFromRestApi( completionHandler: @escaping (_ beacons: [BeaconModel]) -> ()){

    Alamofire.request(Constants.Beacons.URLS.ListAllbeacons).responseArray(keyPath: "data") { (response: DataResponse<[BeaconModel]>) in

        let beaconsArray = response.result.value
        if let beaconsArray = beaconsArray {
            completionHandler(beaconsArray)
        }
    }
}
```

It uses [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). Can you see what I'm missing?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`completionHandler` in `fetchBeaconsFromRestApi` should not throw. So you should wrap all throwing calls with `do - catch`:

```
BeaconModel.fetchBeaconsFromRestApi(completionHandler: {
    beacons in
    for item in beacons{

        let insert = beaconsTbl.insert(id <- item.id!, uuid <- item.uuid!, major <- item.major!, minor <- item.minor!
        do {
            try db.run(insert)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating the database")
        }
    }
})
```